# Temporis and Supernatural beings, what's the effect?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension, vampire-the-dark-ages, werewolf-20th-anniversary

In Vampire Dark Ages 20th Aniversary Edition, Temporis does not specify what is the effect of the ability on supernatural beings (except for the Laquesis Kiss effect on vampires).

For example, would be a werewolf affected by Temporis as a human? Can a Kuei-Jin escape the effects?

Is there a way in wich a supernatural being can evade or counterattack the effects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, this depends on your style as GM. There is no set rule for this because White Wolf has no specific rules on the interaction between the different rulebooks.

You could houserule it in a kind of changeling-way: The closer the being that is affected is to a human, the easier to affect.

Now, after checking the Temporis powers quickly:

1. Doesn't matter.
2. I'd increase the difficulty significantly to put other beings in trance. Up to making it nearly impossible for a werewolf because of their fury.
3. Same here. If the being affected has a power/skill/whatever that could be used like celerity to negate successes, do that as well.
4. Same, I'd say.
5. Doesn't matter.

I didn't check the higher levels. When you're playing/running elders of that level, they do what they want anyway.

Maybe make it cost Willpower, as with mind-reading of unwilling vampires, to show that other beings are more difficult to affect.

In the end, it comes down to how you want to make the other races appear. Do you want to go the "werewolfs are the most dangerous thing there is, don't mess with them, it won't end well"? Then temporis doesn't affect them - their fury burns to hot to be slowed or whatever. You can come up with similar rationales for the other types of supernaturals.